# How to get the current locale in SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm wondering how to get the current locale in a SonataAdmin Admin class.
I know that i could pass for example the requestStack as argument of the admin service but i m wondering if sonata admin provide a method to directly access the current locale.

Comment: Indeed a search of Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin methods would do the trick but some times a google search is more speed.
And for this question a google search doesn't return anything interesting.
It will be not the case anymore i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have access to the `request` (`\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`).

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php#L2225

So `$this->request->getLocale()` would do the trick.